# Regular Expression to split by ;

Tags: c#, regex, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

```
17;#Nancy Williams;#894;#Brian Smith,;#895;#Kart Russell,
```

I tried `;#` RegEx to split but the numbers and the comma after name are not needed.

Also, I have another scenario where the `string` looks like this

```
i:0#.w|domain\nWilliams;i:0#.w|domain\bSmith;i:0#.w|domain\kRussell;
```

Basically, I wanted the end result to look like `domain\username; domain\username2...` and so forth

and same for the first example.

Comment: Why do you not want to parse the first case as an [`SPFieldLookupValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvaluecollection.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(;#)?[0-9]+;#
```

As your regular expression

Comment: Okay, I finally have a situation where input variable looks like domain\username; domain\username2; domain\user3, etc. I am trying to regex ;# to split this into a collection variable. the regex puts the entire string (domain\user1....domain\userNth) into the collection variable. I think the regex ;# to split is not working.

Comment: The string is exactly as you describe "domain\username; domain\username2; domain\user3 ..." if so, the ";#" isn't your separator anymore. Also, it's now a very simple separator and you don't even need a regexp, you can use <string variable>.Split(';')

Comment: Actually, I didn't need the hash #. so all I needed is ; and that did that trick. Thank you Istern.